# don't understand something about <T> and <?>

Tags: java, generics

For example I've got a class

```
class Element {}
```

I've got some classes which are extending this class

```
class ExtraElement extends Element {}
```

**So do this statements are same?**

```
List<Element> list & List<? extends Element>
```

Because as far as I understand `wildcards` define family of classes. And in both statements I can pass any element which extends class `Element` so basically family of `Element` classes.

Comment: Oracle documentation to the rescue: [Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

`List<? extends Element>` could be a `List<ExtraElement>` or it could be a `List<Element>`, but the compiler cannot know which one it is.

If it is a `List<ExtraElement>`, you cannot add a `SomeNonExtraElement` into the list, for example (but you can add a `SomeNonExtraElement` into a `List<Element>`).

To enforce this, the compiler won't let you add *anything* to a `List<? extends Something>`.

Comment: @xehpuk: Not sure. Maybe a literal `null` will be accepted. Please try it and report back. A variable containing `null` will certainly be rejected (as the compiler won't know that it is `null`).

Comment: It wasn't really a question. I just thought you forgot that. A (literal) `null` is always compatible, even for a `List<?>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Fruits> AND List<? extends Fruits>
```

- `List<Fruits>` : In this list you can add any `Fruit` Say `Mango`,`Apple` etc. which are subclasses of `Fruits`
- But in `List<Mango>` you can't add `Apple` as here considering it like this `List<? extends Fruits>` `?` is `Mango` so it's `List<Mango extends Fruits>`.